# Как найти все таблицы в базе данных где первая буква в их имени Z в c#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Например есть таблицы
ZA
и
ZB
и мне их надо найти по букве Z

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: А в чём сложность? Если чистый `sql`, то нужно наверное через специальные таблицы селектить. Если какой-то `ORM` используется, то там по-другому будет, нужно название его указать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-tables.html) можно как-то так:

```sql
SHOW TABLES FROM имя_бд LIKE 'Z%'
```